# Normal vector to a level set and fractional Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, fractional-calculus

Let $U=\{u\le0\}$ and $\partial U=\{u=0\}$. Suppose $\nabla u$ does not vanish on $\partial U$. Then the (canonical extension of the) normal vector field to $\partial U$ (pointing to the interior of $\mathbb R^n \setminus U$ is given by
$$\nu = \frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}.$$

This formula is very helpful in some elliptic problems because it is so related to $\int |\nabla u|^2 = -\int u \Delta u.$

What about elliptic problems with the **fractional** Laplacian $(-\Delta)^s$ ($s \in (0,1)$)?

- Is the existence of a solution in $H^{s}$ or $H^{2s}$ even enough to make sense of the normal vector above?
- Can $\int |(-\Delta)^{s/2}u|^2 = \int u (-\Delta)^s u$ be used to control $\nu$?
- Or do people use a different notion of normal vector?

Comment: I'd guess the tag ([tag:fractional-calculus]) might be suitable here? (I have added it to the corresponding post on [math.se]: [Normal vector to a level set and fractional Laplacian](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4357485).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks!

Comment: @MartinSleziak Should I delete the MSE post? I originally meant to post it only on MO, but made a mistake when logging in.